# Why does my media query not work?

Tags: javascript, html, css, media-queries

My CSS looks like something below:

```
@media  (max-device-width:480px) {
    {
        body{background: red;}
   }
}
```

when I resize the browser to iphone width, I dont see body get red background. Do you guys know what is happening. I also  tried `@media  (max-width:480px)`

FYI I have meta view post tag also set up as:

```
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
```

Comment: I don't think "@media" does what you think it does.

Comment: what do you mean. Do you mean I should add screen option too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`max-width` is right (`max-device-width` would be the screen size, not the window size) but you have extra braces. Take them out:

```
@media  (max-width:480px) {
    body {
        background: red;
    }
}
```

Comment: Cant understand why this question has -2

Answer (score 2):

You have to set it to this

```
@media only screen and (max-width:480px) {

    body{background: red;}

}
```

EDIT
Forgot to explain my changes.

I removed your extra brackets that were inside the media query. But most importantly changed it so that it is only targeting the screen(as stated is optional). And changed `max-device-width` to `max-width` as you have already stated in your `meta` tag that the width should be the value of the device width.

Comment: There are three different changes there. Which are relevant to the question (not all of them are)? Why have you made this a game of spot the difference instead of explaining the changes?

Comment: `screen` is completely optional.

Comment: @Quentin you are correct, sorry about that, it was a quick response(probably would have been better to not respond), edited and added an explanation.